# Unix KSH - split file by character position

Tags: file, unix, split, position, character

I have a large text file (nearly 800MB) and I want to split the file into multiple files. I have list of character/byte position at which I need to split

Example:

```
1 to 1047004 > File1.txt
1047005 to 2092782 >> File2.txt
2092783 to 4183112 >> File2.txt
.
.
.
```

Please help me in finding a suitable command (other than substr) by which I can write chars from position 1 to 1047004 to File1.txt

Comment: most \*nix utilities are line oriented. Are you saying that break between 1047004 and 1047005 is in the middle of a line? Best to edit your question to include at least one of these lines in your data. Also, the `split` utility ***may*** allow for splitting on character count, so check with `man split` and see if you're lucky ;-) Also, if you're testing your code, you won't want to use `>>` for file2/3.. You want to create those file fresh each time, just like `file1`. Good luck.

Comment: sounds to me like it could be done very easily in a C program. probably around 10 lines of code (inside the main function). this is probably easier then using unix shell tools, as they are mostly text and line based, as @shellter said.